# How to get the hash linked to a GeneratedUID in El Capitan?

Tags: security, password, unix, macos

Trying to find the GeneratedUID in OS X still works (see example below):

```
dscl localhost -read /Search/Users/<username> | grep GeneratedUID | cut -c15-
```

But entering the following into the command line, replacing `<GeneratedUID>` with the GeneratedUID found above:

```
cat /var/db/shadow/hash/<GeneratedUID> | cut -c169-216
```

leads to nowhere. This worked in earlier versions of OS X.

Where is the hash located in El Capitan now?

Comment: cannot get hash from GUID anymore in El Capitan...

Answer (score 4):

The hashes of the users are stored in a different place since 10.7:

```
/var/db/dslocal/nodes/Default/users/<user>.plist
```

To get the shadow hash enter:

```
sudo defaults read /var/db/dslocal/nodes/Default/users/<user>.plist ShadowHashData | tr -dc '0-9a-f ' | xxd -p -r | plutil -convert xml1 - -o -
```

or directly through directory services:

```
sudo dscl . read /Users/<user> AuthenticationAuthority
```

and

```
sudo dscl . read /Users/<user> dsAttrTypeNative:ShadowHashData
```

Comment: Triple bonus for figuring out what the user wanted. I was stuck on machine UUID initially. +1

Comment: OMG thats awesome thank you so much wow this is a fabulous community!

Comment: @HenryDanielson What do you need the hashes for? Password cracking?

Comment: yes i was learning how to use John the Ripper I am a technolgy director white hat not for black hat use :) I tried and it didnt work I even logged into root :( Thanks I guess I am missing something

Comment: I dont have root access, though, so how would you suggest getting this hash? I am also firmware locked out, so I can't use SUM, and my account isn't opped, its official status is "Managed, Mobile"